# vuejs expression is not working correctly

Tags: vue.js

what is wrong with my expressions? I am making a rest api call, which works fine. Data loads and gets written to console. I am simply trying to get that data on screen. I can but its not correct. It either shows all of the data. I am only trying to get the first item in the array. items.Name does not work, but it does if I do a v-for="item in items". Regardless it loads everything. When I add a [0] to get the first element, it simply removes all the text except the first letter of the object in the array.What do I need to do?[image]

```html
<p>{{items.Name}}</p>
```

Comment: Show the HTML where you're using `v-for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read the docs about list rendering
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

If you have an `items` array of objects, then you can loop over it in your HTML by using `v-for`, or directly access each entry by specifying the index in the expression: `{{ items[0].Name }}`

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.ID">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Notice you're using `item`, not `items`, inside the `<li>` tag, because you instructed `v-for` to assign the cursor to that variable.